# Change homepage url

Tags: urls, site-url

is there any way how to achieve this? I've tried to google it, but I have no clue how to call it.

`siteurl.com` - for whole web

`siteurl.com/news` - homepage with news

When I add `siteurl.com` I have to by directly redirected to `siteurl.com/new`. It's needed because some google analytics setting or so which will be more precise. Thanks a lot for your help.

EDIT:
`siteurl.com/news` - needs to be "frontpage" and set as "homepage" (theme template issue, it's really complicated to change it to a custom page. Something as "fake url" or so, is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Create a site at `siteurl.com` and create a page `Home`, set it as custom homepage. Then create a page `News` and set it as blog post page to display blog posts. You can do that from `Settings > Reading Settings` section in WordPress admin panel.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not this case. We don't use any blog posts. I simply need change the url which is used for frontpage to site.com/news but it still needs to be the homepage...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this can help you:

use the below code in your theme's `functions.php`

```
function redirect_homepage() {
    if( ! is_home() && ! is_front_page() )
        return;

    wp_redirect( 'http://siteurl.com/news', 301 );
    exit;
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_homepage' );
```

Comment: Please file an [edit] and explain how your code works. Your answer popped up as very low quality. Please take your time and correct your answer. See [answer]

Comment: @PieterGoosen it help for conditionally redirect. please check here for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16738311/redirect-wordpress-homepage-only-301-redirect-if-possible

Comment: That info needs to be **inside** your answer, not a comment. As I said, file an [edit] with the useful info, *i think this can help you:* is useless info

Comment: Also, post the relevant info from the link, *please check here for reference* is also pretty useless if the link is removed

Comment: oh well i understood @PieterGoosen thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I need only change the url. Page is still the one set as homepage/front_page (I don't want to change all the theme), any suggestions?